# How to use a custom framework with a playground in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, swift-playground

I am trying to use a custom framework in a playground as described in this Apple documentation:

http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/9.0/#/devc9b33111c

However, I am unable to get the playground to recognize the framework (https://github.com/gk-brown/MarkupKit). It is a 64-bit Objective-C framework that defines a module.

Here is what I have tried:

- Create a new "single view" playground
- As directed in the document, open the playground and choose *File > Save As Workspace*
- Close the playground
- Open the workspace containing the playground
- Attempt to choose *File > Add Files to [Workspace Name]*

The menu item is actually named "Add Files..." and is disabled. I'm able to work around this by opening the Navigator panel and selecting Project Navigator. The menu item changes to "Add Files to TestPlayground" and becomes enabled.

Moving on, as directed in the document:

- Navigate to the directory containing the framework, select the framework, and click "Add"
- In the editor, open the desired playground source file
- Add an import statement for the framework (e.g. "import MarkupKit")

The console displays the following error:

```
error: TestPlayground.playground:5:8: error: no such module 'MarkupKit'
```

The document additionally notes that the workspace must contain at least one active scheme that builds a target. However, adding a project to the workspace and building it does not resolve the problem. The playground is still unable to see the framework.

Based on what I've read elsewhere on SO, it seems like this should be possible. However, most of the information I have found is 2-3 years old and may be out of date. The framework is a universal binary, and I have tried trimming it using *lipo* as suggested in some other posts. Specifically, I did this:

https://github.com/gk-brown/MarkupKit/wiki/Deployment

Unfortunately, it didn't help.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Hey, were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: Nope. I submitted a bug report to Apple. Will update if I get a response.

Answer (score 0):

You steps looks okay but
**Only missing part I see here is adding a .swift Empty file in the project.**

[image]

**This actually compiles below project so after this framework will be ready to import into the playground.**

Comment: Thanks. I don't have a problem when the framework and playground source are in the same project, as appears to be the case in your example. However, I have not been able to get it to work with a previously built framework. The one I am trying to use is [here](https://github.com/gk-brown/MarkupKit/releases) (MarkupKit-iOS.tar.gz).

Comment: which MarkupKit version are you trying?

Comment: The one in the file I mentioned (MarkupKit-iOS.tar.gz).

Comment: You have shared release link instead share tagged url. https://github.com/gk-brown/MarkupKit/releases/tag/4.0.7 or https://github.com/gk-brown/MarkupKit/releases/tag/4.0.6 which one are you using?

Comment: Only 4.0.7 is currently available as a compiled binary.

Comment: Do you have any active scheme in your project?

Comment: Yes. I followed Apple's instructions.

Comment: Okay, Because when I followed your given link http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/9.0/#/devc9b33111c, I was unable to find Scheme for my project, I have added manually. BTW to add custom framework this link https://m.pardel.net/using-3rd-party-frameworks-in-swift-playgrounds-fd415f6dba10  describes similar steps what I am using in my project shown in above answer.

Comment: I tried the steps in that article a while ago, but I couldn't get it to work. Maybe I'll try it again. Either way, I think the steps in Apple's official docs should work, and they don't. Hopefully they will respond to my bug report at some point.